# Ruby on Rails: How to render file as plain text (without any HTML)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, render, plaintext

How do you render file as a plain/text in rails (without rendering any HTML)?

I've tried:

```
render file: "path/to/file", layout: false
```

and

```
render file: "path/to/file", content_type: 'text/plain'
```

also both

```
render file: "path/to/file", layout: false, content_type: 'text/plain'
```

But there still some html on the response.

I'm using rails 3.2.14 and ruby 1.9.3

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

Silly me, this actually works:

```
render file: "path/to/file", layout: false, content_type: 'text/plain'
```

I was inspecting the element using google chrome, so there's an html tag appears. But when I see the source, there's no HTML tag.

The file I was trying to render is a custom made file without extension, it is a tab separated value I use as a parameter in d3.tsv() (D3.js)

Thank you all for your efforts. :D

**EDIT 2:**

In Edit 1, I checked the response and it's true that it doesn't come with any html tag. But using it as parameter in d3.tsv() (D3.js) doesn't work apparently. Glad I tried [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21129848/881272) from [JetAbe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380733/jetabe) and it works! So I accepted JetAbe's answer.

Comment: what is getting rendered? `layout: false` will apply no layout meaning whats in that file is what you get.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591566/rails-3-render-plaintext-page-using-view

Comment: instead of editing your question , answer it and mark as accepted.so that others know that its solved and don't waste time.

Comment: I'm newbie, can't post my own answer.

Comment: You should be able to do so now. Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you need any further help in this Q drop me a line (either by adding @AngeloNeuschitzer to a comment here or write me an email, see my profile)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think because your env is rails 3 you can try this

```
send_file path_to_file
```

Answer (score 9):

Rails 4.1 now exposes the following API for the `render` method:

`render :plain will set the content type to text/plain
render :html will set the content type to text/html
render :body will not set the content type header.`

In fact, they'll be [deprecating use of `render: text` in a future release.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#rendering-content-from-string)

Comment: For future searchers: In rails 4.0.0, in order to render text you need to write: `render text: "some text"`.  :plain does not work.

Comment: @7stud The opposite appears true.
"We will be deprecating the use of render :text in a future version. So please start using the more precise :plain, :html, and :body options instead. Using render :text may pose a security risk, as the content is sent as text/html."
See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#rendering-content-from-string